# Wp_editor add <p>

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-editor

I'm making a form with wp_editor. So I make that the Wp_editor is required in filling a form. But unfortunetly, Wp_editor adds themself a paragraph < p>. So how to disable this? I try to add

```
$settings = array(
        'wpautop' => false,
    );
```

But nothing change. Also I comment this line in default-filters.php

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop'            );
```

But nothing change again.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

This is [right in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop#Disabling_the_filter). You need to remove the filter completely:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

Since `wpautop` is enabled by default, commenting out the line won't do anything for you.

Comment: Where to add this line? I added but nothing changed again :C

Comment: This should go in your theme's functions.php file